# Add item in listview only if not already present

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview, updates

I would like to add in my Android widget a new item only if this item is not already present in the list.

I tried to use ***contains()*** method but it still doesn't work.

In fact, i get a *JSON object*, and for each JSON object i would like to test if there is already an item corresponding to this JSON objecti in the list.

*If yes, do nothing, if no, add the item on the top of the list.*

Here is my code :

```
//parsing data
        String titre, url, site, ancienprix, nouveauprix, temperature, pseudo, categorie, dealtermine, date, id;

        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;

            SharedPreferences setNbDeal = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            String nbDeal = setNbDeal.getString("nbDeal", "30");

            int nbDeals = Integer.parseInt(nbDeal);

            for(int i=0;i<nbDeals;i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                titre=json_data.getString("titre");
                url=json_data.getString("url");
                site=json_data.getString("site");
                ancienprix=json_data.getString("ancienprix");
                nouveauprix=json_data.getString("nouveauprix");
                dealtermine=json_data.getString("dealtermine");
                temperature=json_data.getString("temperature");
                pseudo=json_data.getString("pseudo");
                categorie=json_data.getString("categorie");
                date=json_data.getString("date");
                id=json_data.getString("id");

                WidgetItem currentItem = new WidgetItem(titre, url, site, ancienprix, nouveauprix, dealtermine, temperature, pseudo, categorie, date);

                if (mWidgetItems.contains(currentItem)){
                    break;
                } else {
                    mWidgetItems.add(currentItem);
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code to declare mWidgetItem :

```
private List<WidgetItem> mWidgetItems = new ArrayList<WidgetItem>();
```

Here is the code of my Widget Item class :

```
public class WidgetItem {
    public String titre, url, ancienprix, nouveauPrix, temperature, site, submitter, categorie, dealTermine, date;


    public WidgetItem(String titre, String url, String site, String ancienprix, String nouveauPrix, String dealTermine, String temperature, String submitter, String categorie, String date) {
        this.titre = titre;
        this.url = url;
        this.site = site;
        this.ancienprix = ancienprix;
        this.nouveauPrix = nouveauPrix;
        this.dealTermine = dealTermine;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.submitter = submitter;
        this.categorie = categorie;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `currentItem` is a pointer to the `WidgetItem`, not the `WidgetItem` itself. Basic Java.

Comment: Can you post the code for the WidgetItem class and also the code where the mWidgetItems variable is declared?

Comment: You need an `equal()` method in your `WidgetItem` class to give you a way of comparing two WidgetItem objects.

Comment: Ok. I have edited the post with declaration of mWidgetItem list and with the code of WidgetItem class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method after adding all element into your list (It removes duplicates):

```
private ArrayList<WidgetItem> getUniqueElements(Collection<WidgetItem> values)
{
    return new ArrayList<WidgetItem>(new TreeSet<WidgetItem>(values));
}
```